# Access to class instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

How can I read a class variable? In my case I can't get value from variable.

```
class MediaContentsController < ApplicationController

  @randomUsrId = rand(100)

  def create        
    puts @randomUsrId
  end

end
```

Comment: Why do you want a class variable in a controller? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: This isn't class variable. It's instance variable in class scope actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `@randomUsrId` refers to an instance variable, not a class variable. You can access it through an instance of the class, not direct on the class. For a class variable, you should use `@@randomUsrId`.

What you are actually looking for is `attr_accessor :randomUsrId`, through this, you can read it on an instance method, and even can set it through an instance of the class.

Here's how:

```
class MediaContentsController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :randomUsrId

  @randomUsrId = rand(100)

  def create
    puts @randomUsrId
  end
end
```

But `@randomUsrId = rand(100)` won't set `@randomUsrId` to a random number, at least it is not the recommend way. You should use `before_action` here.

```
class MediaContentsController < ApplicationController
  attr_accessor :randomUsrId
  before_action :set_user_id_to_a_random_number, only: :create

  def create
    puts @randomUsrId
  end

  private
  def set_user_id_to_a_random_number
    @randomUsrId = rand(100)
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

Each time you call the `set_user_id_to_a_random_number` function, it will generate a different number based on `rand(100)` and store it inside `@randomUsrId`. If that's what you do not want, and you want to persist the same value, you can do something like following:

```
def set_user_id_to_a_random_number
  @randomUsrId = rand(100) unless defined? @randomUsrId
end
```

**Edit**:

What I have stated works only for one request, if you have multiple request, it won't work. As Ryan Bates says [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables?view=comments):

> An instance variable only sticks around for a single request, so using the technique described will only benefit you if you need to call a method multiple times per request.

That leaves you with two options if you want to store something between multiple requests. Either you can go with Databases, or you can use something called [memcached](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore).

Comment: I have got undefined local variable or method `set_user_id_to_a_random_number' for MediaContentsController:Class

Comment: Sorry, it should be have been a symbol, and should be like `:set_user_id_to_a_random_number`, I've edited my answer. Please have a look!

Comment: is it now available only for create method ? I try to get randomUsrId in method index and it's empty. When I add index into before_action it works but value is deffernet :/

Comment: @Dominik I've edited my answer. Please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You probably doing something wrong in your code, since this isn't how Rails controller logic should be usually implemented, but let's get down to your question anyway. As I mentioned it isn't class variable, it's instance variable in class scope, so in order to access it, you should first get it from that scope:

```
class MediaContentsController

  @randomUsrId = rand(100)

  def create
    puts self.class.get_random_usr_id
  end

  def self.get_random_usr_id
    @randomUsrId
  end
end


MediaContentsController.new.create
# => 44
```

Comment: When and how `@randomUsrId = rand(100)` will run, and in what context?

Comment: @ArslanAli _when and how?_ during interpretation, as any other code directive. _in what context?_ in a class context(that is why this variable is accessible by any class method). You can copy-paste this code to your computer and run multiple times.